# Read a csv in azure notebooks

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-notebooks

I am trying to read a csv file on my azure notebook at https://notebooks.azure.com/

I tried to look at the faq https://notebooks.azure.com/faq and I am unable to find the "Data" menu option in my notebook?

I was wondering if this is available only for paid tier or it was removed and the faq was not updated. Should I perform any action or enable it on the notebook?

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upload the csv file to the notebook location in Azure and read it directly with
dat <- read.csv("filename.csv"). No additional path detail is required. You could use File>Upload in the notebook to upload the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your file in the project folder using the upload tab, then use %pwd to find the path and read the CSV file using this path.